# Multitargeting in Xamarin Forms and using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: logging, xamarin.forms

I have recently changed my library from unspecified project to multi targeting. I have class for Netstandard, android and iOS. Each contains this. And then once the platform is targeted the relevant code is called.

```cs
public  partial class PlatformProvider
{
    static IServiceProvider PlatformServiceProvider => new Service();
}
```

I also have shared class

```cs
  public partial class ServiceProvider
  {
      public static IServiceProvider Instance => PlatformServiceProvider;
  }
```

the problem is that I had working logging however after this transition the logging no longer works.

The logging is part of my interface that I use in each platform

```cs
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    Task<bool> Init();
    ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; }
}
    
public class Service : IServiceProvider
{
    private bool _isInitialized;
    private ILogger<RecognitionService> _logger;
    private ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory = NullLoggerFactory.Instance;
    public ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory
    {
         get => _loggerFactory;
         set
         {
          _loggerFactory = value;
          _logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Service>();
         }
        }
        public Service()
        {       
         _logger = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<Service>();
        }
```

And then used like this

```cs
public async Task<bool> Init()
{
    if (_isInitialized) return _isInitialized;
    _isInitialized = await InitService();
    switch (_isInitialized)
    {
         case (false):
              _logger.LogDebug("Error during initialization");
                 break;
          case (true):
              _logger.LogDebug("Initialization ok ");
               break;
     }
            
   return _isInitialized;
}
```

However no logs comes out, I a 100 sure it worked before, could you advise please.

Comment: What is your multitargeting? Have you make the breakpoint to check? All the method in it could not be triggered?

Comment: it is triggered otherwise I would nit say I have issue with logging but something else

Comment: <TargetFrameworks>xamarinios10;monoandroid11.0;netstandard2.0;</TargetFrameworks>

Comment: Have you tried to remove the multitargeting? Does it works like before?